# Lenovo W530 Ubuntu 14.04 discrete graphics mode random crash

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, lenovo

Recently I switched my Lenovo W530 to Ubuntu, and after struggling with Nvidia drivers for about a week I finally got them to work after lots of googling.

Then I was unable to get my second monitor to work using VGA or Mini DisplayPort, or any of the Mini-Dock ports. After googling that issue I was able to resolve it after turning on discrete graphics mode. However when I have discrete mode enabled after a undetermined time Ubuntu will just completely freeze and I have to hard restart to get out of it.

I have tried googling this issue and looking at log that I knew would possibly show anything and did not find anything, if you guys could help that would be awesome. It is a lot easier programming with multiple monitors.

Comment: did you find a solution for you problem ? I have the same laptop, Intel and NVidia Quadro 2000m